# How can i get the elements from an array inside of json in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i have this structure, in  it there is an json object and that object have an array of json objects

i need to ask to them if **color1** is red for example btw

```
name:carla
data: {
   sign: "carly",
   tools: [{trait:color1, value:red}, {trait:color2, value:white}] }
},
name:dany
data: {
   sign: "dan",
   tools: [{trait:color1, value:blue}, {trait:color2, value:black}] 
}
```

so i want to get only the elements have **color1** red, in this case only should i get first one element

i tried with this

```
query = query.where('data.tools', "array-contains", {trait: 'color1', value: 'red'})
```

Comment: see this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72411205/how-can-i-do-the-pagination-without-modifying-the-limit?noredirect=1#72411907

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query fetches documents where `data.tools` contains that object. It *does not* filter that array. You'll need to parse that object yourself after fetching the docs:

```
const qSnap = await query.get();

qSnap.docs.forEach((doc) => {
  const item = doc.data().data.tools.find(t => t.trait === 'color1' && t.value == 'red');
  console.log(item)
})
```

If you are trying to find a specific tool in a document, then you can create a sub-collection for tools. That way, you can query for one specific and also update it directly if required.

Comment: but how can i do the pagination? i mean for example firebase return me 20 and then i filter so i only get 1, but i ask 20

Comment: @signup filter on the number of document returned? You can use `.limit()` in your query like `await query.limit(1).get();`. You cannot limit number of array elements returned. Firestore always returns complete document. Using a sub-collection will allow you to do so.

Comment: for example let query = tokensRef.where('meta', '==', meta)
 
    if (queryPaginated) {
      query = query.limit(queryPaginated)
    } const snapshot = await query.get() //30 qSnap.docs.forEach((doc) => { //4

Comment: i want to get 30 just for say, but later that i filter with your code i will get only 4

Comment: @signup just to confirm, are you trying to retrieve 30 documents? If yes, then you can use `.limit(30)` and Firestore will return 30 docs only even if the query matches thousands

Comment: i dont need just 1, the problem with you anwer is that do a filter with js is not a good idea for pagination, because i will get few than 30

Comment: Like this query.limit(queryPaginated) } const qSnap = await query.get() //30 qSnap.docs. paraCada((doc)

Comment: .limit(30) and then filter i will get fewer