# How can i do the pagination without modifying the limit?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I get the same elements what the user asked?

for example if I do this, the user asked 30

```
query = query.limit(30)
const qSnap = await query.get(); // 30 objects

qSnap.docs.forEach((doc) => { // i will get fewer than 30
  const item = doc.data().data.tools.find(t => t.trait === 'color1' && t.value == 'red');
  console.log(item)
})
```

i need to filter because i have this structure:

```
{
    name:carla
    data: "{
       sign: "carly",
       tools: [{trait:color1, value:red}, {trait:color2, value:white}] }"
    },{
    name:dany
    data: "{
       sign: "dan",
       tools: "[{trait:color1, value:blue}, {trait:color2, value:black}] 
    }"
}
```

or how can i enhacement my structure to dont have this problem?

Comment: what is the name of the library you are using for the  query.limt(), query.get()  calls   Since the only way is to filter the data first, then limit it.  But I'm not familiar with the library to ses if that's possible.

Comment: i am using firebase

Comment: I've added another answer.  Hope it helps.   I suggest having a read through the online documentation to better your understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `array-contains` operations checks if an array, contains a specific (complete) value. It can't check if an array of objects, contains an item with a specific value for a property. The only way is to query the entire object inside the array.

In this example structure:

```
data: {
   sign: "carly",
   tools: [{trait:color1, value:red}, {trait:color2, value:white}] }
}
```

You want to query objects inside a map of an array. See Firestore screenshot below for better visualization:

[image]

To be able to query objects inside a map of an array, you must query the whole object inside of it. See example query below:

```
// As you can see here, you need to be able to jump inside the `data.tools`
// Then query the `tools` array by using objects.
const toolsRef = db.collection("someCollection").where("data.tools", "array-contains",  {trait: "color1", value: "red"})
```

Here's a complete code for reference:

```
const toolsRef = db.collection("someCollection").where("data.tools", "array-contains",  {trait: "color1", value: "red"})
query = toolsRef.limit(30)

query.get()
.then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        // Do anything with the result.
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
});
```

The result should be something like this:

```
5nwzwpxr7BmctvznEypl  =>  {
  name: 'carla',
  data: { tools: [ [Object], [Object] ], sign: 'carly' }
}
```

For more information, See [Array Memberships](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership).

---

### **UPDATE:**

Firestore does not have a way to search from the document's fields which have a JSON object encoded inside. You should parse the JSON object first to get/filter the necessary data. e.g.:

```
query = query.limit(30);
const qSnap = await query.get();

qSnap.docs.forEach((doc) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(doc.data().data);
  const items = data.tools.filter(t => t.trait === "color1" && t.value === "red");
  console.log(items);
})
```

However, the above snippet that is similar to yours could lead into a problem which is not the same as the `limit()` you set on your query. To enhance your structure, I would suggest to put it in document fields like I gave on my original answer above.

```
document
    (fields)
    |- name(string): "carla"
    |- data(map)
            |- sign(string): "carly"
            |- tools(array)
                    |- (map)
                    |   - trait(string): "color1"
                    |   - value(string): "red"
                    |-  (map)
                        - trait(string): "color2"
                        - value(string): "white"
```

This structure is the same as your JSON object encoded inside the `data` field. The advantage of using this structure is you can now query using Firestore which I showed to you on my original post. This would result in 30 documents without using a client side filtering. It will be only fewer than 30 if the query can't find matched documents.

To do this, you just need to construct your JSON object and set the data to the document. See e.g. below:

```
db.collection("someCollection").add({
    data: {
        sign: "carly",
        tools: [{trait: "color1", value:"red"}, {trait:"color2", value:"white"}] 
    },
    name: "carla"
 })
 .then((docRef) => {
     console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
 })
 .catch((error) => {
     console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
 });
```

Comment: data is an string saving a json, tools are an array inside of data, but all is an string

Comment: can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72430700/why-map-is-returning-undefined-and-how-can-i-solve-that/72430765#72430765 please

Answer (score 2):

Taking Stewart's answer and changing it a bit (I couldn't do that in a comment, sorry)

```
const toolsFilter = {
    trait: 'color1',
    value:'red'
  }
 
 const qSnap = await query.where('tools','array-contains-any', toolsFilter)
                          .limit(30)
                          .get();
    
    qSnap.docs.forEach((doc) => { 
      const item = doc.data().data;
      console.log(item)
    }))
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting my slightly incorrect syntax.   My main point to signup was that you need to filter first then limit the data.   I've never used firebase before so just had a look at the online docs to suggest the code as a learning experience for myself.  I've given you a useful answer point because I've learnt something new..

Comment: @Liat did you try it? me no yet

Comment: @Liat are you using this structure },
name:dany
data: {
   sign: "dan",
   tools: [  ????

Comment: I am using structures in arrays, but usually not when I need to query by. When I need to query I will use inner structures (maps) as they are simpler to query. In array you have to match the whole object

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter the data first, them limit it.  Using this synatax.

```
 const toolsFilter = {
    trait: 'color1',
    value:'red'
  }
 
 const qSnap = await query.where('tools','array-contains',toolsFilter)
                          .limit(30)
                          .get();
    
    qSnap.docs.forEach((doc) => { 
      const item = doc.data().data;
      console.log(item)
    }))
```

See the Firebase online documentation for more info on query syntax etc.. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Also this explains pagination using query cursors https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

Comment: but they are in an array

Comment: but they are in an array you answer does not work because  they are in an array

Comment: @signup I've updated to filter on the tools array.  Hope this helps.

Comment: i am getting this error: An error ocurred while retrieving the tokens from DB. TypeError: query.whereArrayContains is not a function

Comment: this whereArrayContains  is used for arrays not json-array

Comment: @signup I've updated to the array-contains where clause.   Does that work for you?