# Why map is returning [undefined]? and how can i solve that?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to filter of my snapshot but i sometimes i am getting [undefined], i dont want to return undefined inside, what is the issue?

```
return snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
  const jn = JSON.parse(doc.data().jsonData)
  const res=  jn.attributes.find(t => t.typet === tokenAttrs[0].name);
  if(res){
    return doc.data()
  }
})
```

Comment: There are a number of answers but I think the question is unclear - what does "I am getting" mean - is that what's returned from this function? What happens if `res` is false? What's returned? Did you check the `jn` and `res` to see what the values are when [undefined] is returned? I think clarifying the question will lead to a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many ways to solve it. One would be to use a foreach and push the new value to an new array. or you filter the empty values from your result before you send it back. like that:

```js
const r = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
      const jn = JSON.parse(doc.data().jsonData)
      const res=  jn.attributes.find(t => t.typet === tokenAttrs[0].name);
      if(res){
        return doc.data()
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }) 
    
// then remove all empty values
return r.filter(n => n)
```

#### with forEach()

```js
const res = []; 
snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
  const jn = JSON.parse(doc.data().jsonData)
  const res=  jn.attributes.find(t => t.typet === tokenAttrs[0].name);
  if (res){
    res.push(doc.data());
  }
}) 

return res;
```

Comment: its not possible to solve without map? just using filter ?

Comment: @signup `return r.filter(n => n)`  will do this job. the workflow is: you fetch the mapping data from snapshot in a new var. for example r. the you can use the filter on r.

Comment: this is the easiest way to solve?

Comment: @signup At least that is not a difficult path. Personally, I would have opted for a forEach loop. Because the purpose of the map function is not to select but to modify.

Comment: i dont care use map, you can change my code

Comment: @signup i updated my answer and add the forEach version.

Answer (score 1):

May it can't find the attribute that match the condition,cause the `res` is undefined. You should check it out.

Comment: how can i solve it?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `filter` function this way:

```
return snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
    const jn = JSON.parse(doc.data().jsonData);
    const res = jn.attributes.find(t => t.typet === tokenAttrs[0].name);

    if (res) return doc.data();
}).filter(_ => _ !== undefined);
```

This will remove the `undefined` values from the array.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.find` will search through the array and gets all the match data. If nothing is found, it returns `undefined`. You just need to create a logical `OR` expression. See code below:

```
return snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
      const jn = JSON.parse(doc.data().jsonData)
      // will now return null if there's no matched data.
      const res =  jn.attributes.find(t => t.typet === tokenAttrs[0].name) || null;
      if(res){
        // this will not return if `res` is null
        return doc.data()
      } else {
        // you could do `else` here if you want to do something if there's no matched data.
        // Do something
      }
    })
```